# Info (10008): Verilog HDL or VHDL information: EDA Netlist Writer cannot regroup multidimensional array

Tags: arrays

I am prototyping some code before beginning a larger project. The code runs through simulation ok but when I try to synthesize it I get the message: Info (10008): Verilog HDL or VHDL information: EDA Netlist Writer cannot regroup multidimensional array "arr1" into its bus.

I have searched the internet thoroughly and can't find recommendations on how to address the issue. Multidimensional arrays should synthesize.

```
include "Incl.sv"
module Mod (input reg clk, input reg d, input start, output reg out);
    parameter var1 = 16'b0000000011111111;
    ifdef maxad 
        integer ad = maxad;
    endif
    ifdef maxbd 
        integer bd = maxbd;
    endif  
    logic [15:0] arr1 [0:maxad][0:maxbd]; 
    integer i;
    integer j; 
    logic   init;
    always @ (posedge clk) 
    begin
        if (start == 1'b1)
        begin
            for(j = 0; j < maxad+1; j = j + 1)
            begin
                for (i = 0; i < maxbd+1; i = i + 1)
                begin
                    arr1[j][i] = var1;
                end //end i
            end //end j
            init = 1'b1;        
        end //end start and clk
        else if (init == 1'b1 && start == 1'b0)
        begin
            for(j = 0; j < `maxad+1; j = j + 1) //a works here 
            begin
                for (i = 0; i < `maxbd+1; i = i + 1)
                begin
                    out = ~d; 
                    arr1[j][i] = arr1[j][i] + 1'b1;
                    ad = ad + 1;
                    bd = bd + 1;
                end // end i
            end // end j
        end // end init start clock
    end //end always
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

can u please elaborate ur use case ; what kind scenario u are trying to implement in Hardware. I think the verilog code u are using will result in syntax errors. please try to use the below code . even though i didn't get full picture of use case , i modified the code such that it will synthesize and u can modify from this point to match ur functionality.

```
module Mod ( input logic  clk,
             input logic  d,
             input        start,
             output logic out
          );

 parameter var1 = 16'b0000_0000_1111_1111;

localparam MAXAD = 4;

localparam MAXBD = 4;
integer ad =4,bd=4;
logic [15:0] arr1 [MAXAD][MAXBD];
integer i;
integer j;
logic   init;

    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (start) begin
                    arr1 <= #1 '{default:var1};
                    init <= #1 1'b1;
        end else if (init) begin
            for(j = 0; j < MAXAD; j = j + 1) begin
                for (i = 0; i < MAXBD; i = i + 1)begin
                    out <= #1 ~d;
                    arr1[j][i] <= #1 arr1[j][i] + 1'b1;
                    ad <= #1 ad + 1;
                    bd <= #1 bd + 1;
                end // end i
            end // end j
        end // end init start clock
    end //end always
endmodule
```

Comment: Made your change and received the following: 
Error (10734): Verilog HDL error at Mod.sv(11): ad is not a constant
Error (10734): Verilog HDL error at Mod.sv(11): bd is not a constant
Error (10161): Verilog HDL error at Mod.sv(23): object "d" is not declared. Verify the object name is correct. If the name is correct, declare the object.

Comment: And btw thank you for your suggestions. My use case is that this is just a prototype for larger and more complex arrays that were receiving the same message during synthesis. So, I reduced it down to one much more simple array but still get the same message. If I can fix the simple case I am good to go for the larger version.